# java CharsetDetector: How to detect ASCII

Tags: java, character-encoding, charset

i am using CharsetDetector to detect the charset of a text file.

This is the code to detect the charset of the given file:

```
private String getCharset(File file) {
        String charset = "";
        try {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            CharsetDetector cd = new CharsetDetector();
            cd.setText(bis);
            CharsetMatch cm = cd.detect();
            if (cm != null) {
               Reader reader = cm.getReader();
               charset = cm.getName();
            }
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return charset;
    }
```

For a ASCII text file it returns UTF-8. ASCII is a subset of UTF-8 but i like to detect ASCII if it is ascii only and UTF-8 if there is a sign which is not in ASCII.

But how can i check it?

Comment: For reference, the full list of charsets that CharsetDetector recognises is [here](https://github.com/prepare/icu4j/blob/master/main/classes/core/src/com/ibm/icu/text/CharsetDetector.java#L476). US_ASCII is not one of them.

Comment: You might be able to use another detector that _does_ know about ASCII, such as [juniversalchardet](https://github.com/albfernandez/juniversalchardet).

Comment: In your code replace your call to `cd.detect()` with a call to `cd.detectAll()` which will return an array of possible charsets. You can then process the elements of the returned array as appropriate. But I think you are needlessly creating difficulties for yourself by wanting to use `CharsetDetector` because it is not the best way to solve your specific problem. See the accepted answer to [Tika is not detecting plain ascii input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64936691/2985643) for an explanation...

Comment: ... So instead of using `CharsetDetector` to determine whether the charset of your file is (potentially) ASCII, simply process the file's data yourself. There are multiple ways to do that in Java. Review the many answers to [How to check if a String contains only ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3585053/2985643) and pick an approach that meets your needs.

Answer (score 1):

First, I reviewed your code and want to put out some hints:

1. Your method first reads through the entire file to detect the character set using *CharsetDetector*, and then it read through the file again to check if all the characters are ASCII. For large files, this can be inefficient since you are **essentially doubling the I/O operations** required.
2. In your code, if the *CharsetMatch* was *null* (i.e., the CharsetDetector couldn't determine the charset), you returned an empty string. You may want to return a sensible default charset or handle this case explicitly.

My suggestion would be to improve your method like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class CharsetDetection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("path_to_your_file.txt");
        String charset = getCharset(file);
        System.out.println("Detected Charset: " + charset);
    }

    private static String getCharset(File file) {
        String charset = "UTF-8"; // Default to UTF-8
        boolean isPureAscii = true;

        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
             BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is)) {

            int b;
            while ((b = bis.read()) != -1) {
                if (b > 127) { // Non-ASCII character found
                    isPureAscii = false;
                    break; // No need to continue checking, it's not ASCII
                }
            }

            // If all characters are ASCII, set charset to US-ASCII
            if (isPureAscii) {
                charset = "US-ASCII";
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return charset;
    }
}
```

This method is more efficient because it only requires a single pass through the file and stops as soon as it finds a non-ASCII character. However, it doesn't use the CharsetDetector class. If you need to detect character sets other than ASCII and UTF-8, you might need a more complex solution.

Good Luck!

Comment: Just because it's not ASCII doesn't mean it could be UTF-8. A simple solution would be to add to your line: `if (usPureAscii) charset = "US-ASCII" else /* use CharsetDetector */`

Comment: You are right. My solution resolves the case when you are sure it is UTF-8 and want to determine if it is also ASCII or not. As I mentioned, it requires adjustment, if someone is looking to detect more character sets using my code above.

Comment: While it's appropriate that you offered an approach to solve the OP's question without using `CharsetDetector`, the problem you are solving (i.e. verifying that data only contains ASCII characters in Java) is a very basic one, and has been asked many times on SO. So before answering any question on SO (even ones which seem obscure!), please check first that it has not already been asked and answered. If so, then flag the question as a duplicate rather than answering it.